# Many to Many relationships with unique values in a junction table

Tags: database, sqlite, flask, model, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to build a website with Flask, and I have some issues coming up with appropriate models for the database. I am making an app that would function like a book club.

Here are the details for coming up with the model:

1. one user can add many books
2. one book can be read by many users
3. each user will HAVE to add one (and only one) status tag for each book (that says either read, to be read, or being read)

I am struggling to come up with an appropriate model for this. I am using flask-sqlalchemy.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, default = urlsafe_b64encode(uuid().bytes)[0:10], primary_key=True) #unique id
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    bookstatus = db.relationship('BookStatus', backref='user', lazy=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)

class BookStatus(db.Model):
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True)
    added_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    
class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gbook_id = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    added_by = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),
        nullable=False)
    bookstatus = db.relationship("BookStatus", backref='book', lazy=True)
```

I have been told that the junction table for the many-to-many relationship for the book should be defined as just a table and not through a class, but I am not sure how to include the status column. Do I then use a one-to-one relationship for the table and the bookstatus class? Or am I completely wrong!!

Please help! I have been struggling to solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-many relationship is represented by BookStatus model and corresponding table in the database.
So here are your models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.String, default = urlsafe_b64encode(uuid().bytes)[0:10], primary_key=True) #unique id
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)

class BookStatus(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book_status'
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True)
    added_by = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum('read', 'to be read', 'being read'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[added_by])
    book = db.relationship('Book', foreign_keys=[book_id])
    
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'book'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gbook_id = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
```

I have changed your BookStatus.status attribute to be enum type. You can use Integer, for example 0 (being read), 1 (to be read) and 2 (read) but I think that enum type is better to use in this situation.

In the ORM (object-relational mapping) and relational database design every entity(object, table) needs to have only property which can describe that entity. For example Book.added_by cannot, or more precisely should not represent as a book's attribute. Same situation is for User.book_status. User is not a book.

Book's status as a property needs to be the attribute of the book's entity (if that status represent a book in terms of quality). In your situation book_status is related with a junction table(entity) - BookStatus (many-to-many relation between user and book).